# Small offset when calculating rotation based on touch point

Tags: java, android, math, libgdx

I need to have a sprite face the cursor/touch point. 
The vector of the touch point is calculated as follows:

```
game.getCamera().unproject(
new Vector3().set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0)
, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight())
```

And then I calculate the degrees the sprite needs to turn with the following method:

```
public void rotateTo(Vector3 vector) {
    double angle = Math.atan2(vector.y - position.y, vector.x - position.x);
    rotation = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle) - 90;
    sprite.setRotation(rotation);
}
```

The problem is that there is a small offset in some rotations for example(The red dot indicates the touch position and the arrow is the sprite that needs to be rotated), in the first picture its roughly where it should be but in the others its way off, what could be causing this bug?:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the first 2 pictures with a small change in the X axis the accuracy decreases dramatically.

More examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but be careful doing things like `rotation = (float) Math.toDegrees(angle) - 90;` I think in this instance it actually will do the subtraction first and then cast that result as a float, causing a loss of precision by a fairly substantial margin for angles. Or I could be wrong. Either way, it's usually best to be explicit about your casts. Perhaps `rotation = ((float) Math.toDegrees(angle)) - 90f;` where the f makes the 90 a float, and the (float) cast applies only to the method `toDegrees`

Comment: OH, also, my original thought: Make sure you have the origin of the sprite set somewhere along the line of the arrow instead of something like the top-left corner. This is likely your issue :)

Comment: @ChristopherWirt Tried doing `sprite.setOriginCenter();`, same results I think libgdx sets the origin to the center as default.

Comment: But is the sprite center actually along the axis of the arrow? This would make it look like it was off.

Comment: @ChristopherWirt yup the sprite is 60 pixels wide and the arrows center is at 30 exactly at the center.

Comment: The `origin` should be the lower, left corner by default. You should set it to `width/2`, `height/2`

Comment: @Springrbua as I said above already tried doing that.

Comment: @Nick i know i just wrote it cause you said that you think libgdx sets the `origin` to the center by default. Just to let you know that the default should be the lower left corner

Comment: That's not true. The origin is in the center by default, relative to the position which is always in the lower left corner. Take a look at the source of Sprite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position is in the lower left regardless of the origin, because origin is relative to position. So you are calculating the angle based on the lower left of the sprite instead of the center. You need to offset the position by the origin if you want to measure your angle relative to the center of the sprite.

```
double angle = Math.atan2(
    vector.y - position.y - spriteOrigin.y, 
    vector.x - position.x - spriteOrigin.x);
```

Also keep this in mind when drawing your sprite...it's position is always in the lower left, so take that into account when setting its position.

Comment: To obvious :P Good that you noticed that! +1